# HTML hover oon text

Tags: html, css, character-encoding

I have a table where I have a text. I have made the following code so that when you hover over it, a small text appears.
= "<a title = " "+" Hello "+" \ "href = " # \ "style = " text-decoration: none; color: white; \ ">" + "Hover on me" + ""

What I want is to be able to hover over the entire column and then comes the text. (preferably even bigger if possible)

Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```css
.hoverText{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%; height: 200px;">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a title="Hover Text 1" href="#" class="hoverText">Hover on me 1</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a title="Hover Text 2" href="#" class="hoverText">Hover on me 2</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a title="Hover Text 3" href="#" class="hoverText">Hover on me 3</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a title="Hover Text 4" href="#" class="hoverText">Hover on me 4</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Thanks and best regards!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a hover effect on the cell, you must apply it the whole cell, and not only to the text.
So, add it in the td- Tag, not to the text.

Or did I understand your question wrong?

Comment: How do you mean? Sorry completly new at HTML :)